# how to change /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 path to a custom one

Tags: c++, linux, glibc

I I cross compile glibc but do not have permission to access root /, and I want to use this external libc to run some bin, but it prompt me "No such file or directory" except i put the ld-linux-armhf.so.3 to /lib/, how to change the default load path, for ex, my default full path is in /system/usr/local/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3

Comment: I try to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/system/usr/local/lib, but it does not work

Comment: Is your executable in your PATH? And what if you run your executable with its full path? Lastly, what does ldd say about your executable and the dynamic libraries that it wants to load?

Comment: yes,i did. and i solve this thanks for Employed Russian by using [code]-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/to/newglibc/ld-linux.so.2[code].